# readable columns names in my CSV file that is exported from elastic search?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, elasticsearch, python-3.6

Below is the code that is grabbing some data from elastic search and exporting that data to a csv file called ‘mycsvfile’.
I want to change the column names so that it is readable by a human.
Below is the code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(["9200"])

# Replace the following Query with your own Elastic Search Query
res = es.search(index="search", body=
                {
                    "_source": ["DTDT", "TRDT", "SPLE", "RPLE"],
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {"wildcard": {"CN": "TEST1"}}

                            ]
                        }
                    }
}, size=10)



with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writeheader()
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

when I run the above query the CSV file data look like below:

```
DTDT    TRDT    SPLE    SACL    RPLE

20170512    12/05/2017 15:39    1001    0   0

20170512    12/05/2017 15:39    1001    0   0

20170908    08/09/2017 02:42    1001    0   0

20170908    08/09/2017 06:30    1001    0   0
```

As you can see the column names are the same as in the query and I want to give them readable names when the file is being generated. For example, instead of DTDT I would like to have DATE and TRDT would be TIME etc

Could someone show and fix my code up for me to enter column names to the CSV file?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry, wrote that line out of my behind. The correct, tested, version is as follows.

```
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            fieldnames = ['name', 'name', 'name']
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            w.writeheader()
            header_present = True

        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

What made your script write out the headers was the my_dict.keys() as passed to the DictWriter. Replacing those keys with a list of labels, the writer should write it properly.

Comment: i replaced 'w.writerow(my_dict)' with your answer of - w.writeheader('column_name', 'column_name', 'column_name', 'column_name').

But i am getting a error now saying-  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/.PyCharmCE2017.2/config/scratches/test1.py", line 28, in <module>
    w.writeheader('column_name', 'column_name', 'column_name', 'column_name')
TypeError: writeheader() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given.

is it becuase i got get of my_dict inside the w.writeheader?

Comment: thanks for taking a look, i run the code and it creates the file however its not grabbing my data anymore? is there something missing in the code?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to just use a dict as a conversion table and write it as a row instead of writing the actual DictWriter header:

```
header_names = { 'DTDT': 'DATE', 'TRDT': 'TIME', ...}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'w') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    header_present  = False
    for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
        my_dict = doc['_source'] 
        if not header_present:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
            w.writerow(header_names)  # will write DATE, TIME, ... in correct place
            header_present = True


        w.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: that worked! thank you so much! would you know how to create my file called 'mycsvfile with the current date & time at the end of the file name for when i run the query the name should be mycsvfile20121012 - 08:46